# getting date lastupdated working erratically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that gets the lastupdated date from a spreadsheet and enters it into a dashboard so we now the data is current. I use this for several different department dashboards. For some reason it will work on some as expected when the dashboard is opened, on others I have to run it manually, and now this time it will only place the date on the second file it checks and for some reason skips the first one. I have copied this from sheet to sheet and it will work on on but not the other. Cant seem to make sense of this. Any help appreciated

```
function LAstUpdate() {
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Wetmore Delivered");
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var id = file.getId();
        var lastUpdated = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var cell = ss.getRange("Dashboard!o9").setValue(lastUpdated); 
    }
}

function LAstUpdate() {
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Wetmore Accepted");
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var id = file.getId();
        var lastUpdated = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var cell = ss.getRange("Dashboard!J9").setValue(lastUpdated);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a simple trigger (`onOpen()`) to run this function or you using an installed trigger to run this? Secondly, how many files do you normally have per folder? Finally, have you looked at the [execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript)?

Comment: Also, this line `var cell = ss.getRange("Dashboard!o9").setValue(lastUpdated);` always sets value of cell `O9` to the `lastUpdate` immaterial of howmany files you have!

Comment: @JackBrown these must be installed triggers due to the necessary authorization scopes (SpreadsheetApp R&W, DriveApp Read). It's likely some departments have set up the trigger, while others didn't. Only the user who creates a trigger can see it, so a third party can't inspect trigger status. As you mention, due to the in-loop call to `setValue`, only the value from the last-read file will persist. **@ OP**: Rename your methods so each has a unique name (or better yet, a common function taking a file name (to search), a range (to write to), and write an array of values after the loop finishes.